# XSL - How to check if current node has no text and if true add text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Below code assigns Y or N to element ABC if property 1234 is found and boolean1 value.
But sometimes property id 1234 is not at all present in /Response/Specification/Section/item/Property.
So the element ABC remains empty in output xml.
I want to set Element value to N when property 1234 is not present.
I am very new to to XSL and XML.

Input XML where each specification tag contains multiple section and item. Where each section and item has its own id.

`<Response>
    <Specification>
        <Section>
            <sectionid>9999</sectionid>
            <item>
                <itemid>8888</itemid>
                <property>
                    <id>1234</id>
                    <property>ABC<property>
                    <boolean1>1</boolean1>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <id>5678</id>
                    <property>XYZ<property>
                    <boolean1>0</boolean1>
                </property>
                </property>
                <property>
                </property>
            </item>
            <item>
            </item>
            <item>
            </item>
        </Section>
        <Section>
        </Section>
        <Section>

        </Section>
    </Specification>
</Response>`

Small sample of well formed input xml.

```
<Response>
<Specification>
    <Section>
        <Sectionid>9999</Sectionid>
            <Item>                
                <Itemid>8888</Itemid>
        <Property>
                        <id>1234</id>
                    <Property>ABC</Property>
                        <Boolean1>1</Boolean1>
                </Property>
                <Property>
                        <id>5678</id>
                        <Property>XYZ</Property>
                        <Boolean1>0</Boolean1>
                </Property>                
            </Item>
</Section>     
</Specification>
</Response>
```

In the original post I had removed some of the elements. I though it would make it short and simple. Below is updated xsl with all elements

```
<ABC>
<xsl:for-each select="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property[id=1234]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="boolean1=1" >
            <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>                 
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</ABC> 
<XYZ>
<xsl:for-each select="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property[id=5678]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="boolean1=1" >
            <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>                 
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</XYZ>
```

Expected output XML has just parenttag which contains all other tags like ABC, XYZ, PQR etc. When property id 1234 is not present, output is empty ABC tag. Here we want to add N instead of empty tag.

```
<parenttag>
</ABC>
<XYZ>N</XYZ>
</parenttag>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple **property** (or is it **Property**? Remember XML, and XSLT, is case-sensitive), I would start off by iterating over the **property** elements, but without checking any values at this point

```
<xsl:for-each select="Response/Specification/Section/item/property">
```

Within this, if you are wanting to create an element with a name based on the child **property** element, you can use **xsl:element** together with an Attribute Value Template to specify the element name dynamically.

```
<xsl:element name="{property}">
```

Then, within this, you can have an **xsl:choose** when you test your conditions, including the check on "1234"

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ID=1234 and BOOLEAN1=1" >
        <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>         
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <parenttag>
         <xsl:for-each select="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property">
            <xsl:element name="{Property}">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="id=1234 and Boolean1=1">
                     <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </parenttag>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If the element names depend on the IDs, and you want them always to be present, you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <parenttag>
         <ABC>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property[id=1234]/Boolean1=1">
                  <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </ABC>
         <XYZ>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property[id=5678]/Boolean1=1">
                  <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </XYZ>
      </parenttag>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although, to avoid code repetition, you could use named templates. Try this to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <parenttag>
         <ABC>
            <xsl:call-template name="check">
               <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'1234'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </ABC>
         <XYZ>
            <xsl:call-template name="check">
               <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'5678'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </XYZ>
      </parenttag>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="check">
      <xsl:param name="id"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="Response/Specification/Section/Item/Property[id=$id]/Boolean1=1">
            <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes we have multiple properties around 50. Each element contains text just Y or N. Tried above solution, it is giving string of Y and N as you have said. But we want only Y or N. Could you guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed a sample of your input XML, and the output you expect. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have updated the post with input xml, output xml and updated xsl. Please let me know if this information helps. Thank you.

Comment: Can you make sure both your input and output XML is well-formed please? Also, where does PQR come from, as I can't see in anywhere in the input XML? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tim, I had added PQR just for example. Sorry for that, removed it from output. Thanks.

Comment: I've re-written my answer to hopefully provide the solution now.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your solution. I compared the child property names values with XSL tag names.  Most of the times they are different except few and also child property names are in lower case.  All XSL tag names are hardcoded. Because of this when any property is not present in input XML, it is still present in output XML but empty. Is their any alternate way that you can suggest.

Comment: I've made some more suggestions in my answer. I hope this finally answers your question because I am not quite sure what else to suggest at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tim, after applying the XSLT output XML showed N in both cases that is when property was present or absent in input XML. Could it be due to For each select is not used? Meanwhile I have thought of other approach. Is it possible to set XSL tag with N as default value and if property is found with boolean1 = 1 then overwrite N with Y?

Comment: Do make sure to check the element names in the XSLT. As I mentioned before, it is case-sensitive. In the XML sample you provide you have a **property** (all lower case), but in your XSLT you refer to **Property** with a capital "P". This means I have had to make some guesses in my answer. To avoid such guessing it would help if you showed a small, but representative (and well formed) sample of your input XML, and the (well-formed) output XML you expect. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that Tim, I have added small sample of well formed input XML below the old one.

Comment: I have made one final edit to my answer. You can see it in action over at http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8q

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried this but I am not sure what is the issue with our xsl. it did not work. Due to time crunch we opted to update the xml through Pl/Sql code. Thanks a lot for your suggestions and help :)